# Asp Mvc resize image on client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, image-resizing

I want to enable the user to upload an image ,but i want the image to be resized at the cliet side ,before pass it to the server. So if the image to large it won't take long time.
Is any way to achieve that using JS or any tools ,
BTW I'm coding in Asp Mvc 5.

Answer (score 0):

Changing image size after file select input change event :

```
    <input type="file" id="fileSelect">
    <img id="preview">
 <script>
    document.getElementById('fileSelect').onchange = function(event) {
    ImageTools.resize(this.files[0], {
    width: 720, 
    height: 480
    }, function(blob, didItResize) {
    //it will be true if it resize it, else false and will return the original file as blob
    document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   });
  };
 </script>
```

Update :
you need to add refrence for imagetools :

```
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dcollien/312bce1270a5f511bf4a/raw/155b6f5861e844310e773961a2eb3847c2e81851/ImageTools.js"></script>
```

Comment: not working, it says TypeError: window.ImageTools is undefined.

Comment: @khalidAlJahury you should add refrence for it , i updated post.

Comment: Does it resize the file itself or just the img element,

Comment: it will resize image after file select.